# Yii 2.0 CSRF validation for AJAX request

Tags: php, yii2, csrf

I have an `ajax` function that triggers an entry deletion from my database.

I need to do `CSRF` validation for the same. How can I do that?

I am sending the `CSRF cookie` along with my post request, but `Yii 2.0` is not validating it and any input that is passed through ajax is reaching the server.

How do I do `CSRF` validation for ajax requests.

Whether we need to manually set cookie and check?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to manually set cookie.

If you are using jQuery CSRF token will be sent automatically.

For example for AngularJS you can add it manually to request params like that:

```
yii.getCsrfParam(): yii.getCsrfToken()
```

Make sure you have `YiiAsset` included.

Otherwise you can retrieve them from meta tags (that's basically what these two methods do):

```
$('meta[name=csrf-param]').prop('content'): $('meta[name=csrf-token]').prop('content')
```

Also note that for enabling CSRF validation both `Controller`'s and `Request`'s property `enableCsrfValidation` property must be set to `true`.

**Update:**

Another important thing to understand:

CSRF token will be validated only on this methods: `GET`, `HEAD`, `OPTIONS`.

Also make sure you have `<?= Html::csrfMetaTags ?>` in main layout.

Comment: Bu how will it validate..What should I write in controller action to check whether it is validated or not?

Comment: What do you mean by validation?

Comment: I mean when somebody sends data without proper csrf data, he should not be able to do the controller action

Comment: It's done automatically for every request. And by default CSRF validation is enabled. [Here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/web/Controller.php#L109) is exact place where it's validated (`yii\web\Controller beforeAction()`).

Comment: But in my case it I can access the action even if I am not sending the token

Comment: I see two possible reasons. 1) You disabled it somewhere (in application config or at runtime). 2) CSRF meta tags are missing. Make sure have `Html::csrfMetaTags` in your layout. For example see [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/frontend/views/layouts/main.php#L20).

Comment: I am including the following in main layout 
    <?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>

Comment: Then I recommend to check the value of `var_dump(\Yii::$app->controller->enableCsrfValidation)`.

Comment: @ arogachev : it returns  bool(true)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77446/discussion-between-arogachev-and-jinu-joseph-daniel).

Comment: Finally I identified that I just need to do 
    <?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?> in main layout..Nothing else neeeded.It is working because I included that in main layout.I f I remove it exception will be thrown.Dont even need to manually send the csrf along with the request :|

Answer (score 1):

Please let me add some optional answer i found at [this page](https://www.codesiri.com/2015/01/yii2-using-csrf-token.html),

```
    <head>
       .......
       <?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>
    </head>
    .......
<script>
    var csrfToken = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content");
    $.ajax({
             url: 'request',
             type: 'post',
             dataType: 'json',
             data: {param1: param1, _csrf : csrfToken},
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I identified that just including

```html
    <?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>
```

in mail layout will automatically add csrf validation to every post / get requests whether it is ajax or not.We dont need to manually send csrf token along with aja

```html
    <?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>
```

the request is failing and throwing the exception..So it was my mistake..Just adding 
    `<?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>`

will do csrf validation whether it is ajax or non ajax request / form submission..

Hats off to  Yii 2.0 inventors for such an awesome stuff #love-yii-2.0