# ajax error 400 bad request

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii2

I am trying to upload file using ajax in yii2.
but it browser console it shows 400 Bad Request in my site_url
what is my mistake..
Please help anyone.

```
var site_url = '<?php echo Url::to (['formdata/movefile','id'=>'']); ?>' + unic ;
                 var file_data = $('#formdata-'+ form + '-' + component + '-c_data').prop('files')[0];
                      var form_data = new FormData();                  
                      form_data.append('file', file_data);

                       $.ajax({
                    url: site_url, // point to server-side PHP script 
                    dataType: 'TEXT',  // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    data: { form_data:form_data,_csrf : '<?=Yii::$app->request->getCsrfToken()?>'},                         
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function(php_script_response){
                       alert(php_script_response);
                    }
         });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you enable enableCsrfValidation in you yii2 project, you need to add a token to ajax data to make the request validate.

@see

[CSRF](https://yii2-cookbook.readthedocs.io/csrf/)

[CSRF Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30153705/yii-2-0-csrf-validation-for-ajax-request)

Comment: yaa.. its crct... My mistake is in csrf enable validation

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set contentType to json, as you are sending json data

```
contentType: "application/json"
```

So your ajax request will be something like this

```
$.ajax({ url: site_url, dataType: 'TEXT',  cache: false, contentType: "application/json", processData: false, data: { form_data:form_data,_csrf : '<?=Yii::$app->request->getCsrfToken()?>'}, type: 'POST', success: function(php_script_response){ alert(php_script_response); }
```

You can also get `400 Bad request` error if you are not sending the data to server as described in its documentation. ( usually missing certain parameters or headers )

Comment: sry.. Now also its showing same error                                        jquery.min.js:4 POST http://localhost/basic/index.php?r=formdata%2Fmovefile&id=45bc9afa37281707 400 (Bad Request)
send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ index.php?r=formdata%2Fcreate&id=31:493
each @ jquery.min.js:2
each @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ index.php?r=formdata%2Fcreate&id=31:471
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3

Comment: @Prabhakaran Are u passing all parameters as described in documentation?

Comment: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.   what is this error

Comment: add error:{} callback section (similar to success) after success and print the err to console

Comment: @Prabhakaran network calls should not happen in main thread. It usually happens if you set `async:false` in the jquery ajax request

Comment: ya.. its crct, I use 3 ajax in a page.. i my 2nd ajax i use async:false, Now the error msg is removed

Comment: but bad request is coming continuously

Answer (score 0):

i found my mistake..

There was csrf token mistake in my controller action.. so i add this following code in controller

```
public function beforeAction($action)
    {
        if (in_array($action->id, ['movefile'])) {
            $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
        }
        return parent::beforeAction($action);
    }
```

Now its working perfectly

Thanks to all :-)))))))